# Puppeteer: How to click element so it opens in new tab?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have got a list of 25 elements that are clickable. I need to open each one of them in a new tab, scrape the new page opened in a new tab, then close it. Then go to the next element and do the same for each element in the list.

however, I am having problems opening the links in a new tab by clicking on them. I managed to open then with `page.goto('link")` but I want to make it more humanized and instead of pasting the link into the new tab I want to be opened by clicking.

```
let accountsClickElements = await page.$$eval(".result-lockup__name a", el => el.map(x => x.getAttribute("id")));
                                                                                        
 for (let i = 0; i<25; i++) {
     await autoScroll(page);
     await page.waitFor(3000);
     let id = companies[i];
     await page.focus("#"+accountsClickElements[0]);
     accountsClickElements = await page.$$eval(".result-lockup__name a", el => el.map(x => x.getAttribute("id")));
     await page.waitFor(3000);
     await page.focus("#"+accountsClickElements[i]);                             
     await page.click("#"+accountsClickElements[i]);
     await page.waitFor(2000);
     console.log("#"+companies[i].linid);
     await page.goBack(); 
  }                              `
```

This is a code that opens the links in the same tab, but after a while, it doesn't take all 25 elements and since id is changing every time I open the page I get an error.

I have changed the code like this so instead of clicking of the element, it is clicking on the href attribute. the target _blank attribute is there, but it still opening on the same tab. Can you point why?

```
await page.$$eval('.result-lockup__name a', el => el.map(x => x.setAttribute("target", "_blank")));
let accountsClickElements = await page.$$eval(".result-lockup__name a", el => el.map(x => x.getAttribute("href")));                                                                                                                  
for (let i = 0; i<25; i++) {
   await page.waitFor(2000);
   await autoScroll(page);
   await page.waitFor(2000);    
   await page.click('a[href="'+accountsClickElements[i]+'"]');
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Middle click using [`page.click`](https://pptr.dev/#?show=api-pageclickselector-options):

```
let options = {button : 'middle'};
await page.click('a[href="'+accountsClickElements[i]+'"]', options)
```

It might take some time for the new tab to open, which you can wait for with `await page.waitForTimeout(1000)`.

Full code:

```
let accountsClickElements = await page.$$eval('.result-lockup__name a', el => el.map(x => x.getAttribute('href')));

browser.on('targetcreated', function(){                                            
    console.log(accountsClickElements[i]) 
})   

let options = {
    button : 'middle'
};
for (let i = 0; i<25; i++) {
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
    await page.focus('a[href="'+accountsClickElements[i]+'"]')                                                    
    await page.click('a[href="'+accountsClickElements[i]+'"]', options)
    const [tab1, tab2, tab3] = await browser.pages();
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
    await tab3.bringToFront();                                                                               
    await ListenCompanyPageNewTab(tab3); 
    await tab2.bringToFront();                                                            
}
```

Answer (score 8):

On **Windows** or **Linux**, [hold down the Ctrl key](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179#zippy=%2Cmouse-shortcuts) before you click:

```js
    // Ctrl+click to open in new tab
    await page.keyboard.down('Control');
    await page.click('a[href="'+accountsClickElements[i]+'"]')
    await page.keyboard.up('Control');
```

Then find the tab that was opened. One way to do that is with `await browser.pages()` and filtering out the current page. Note that when you start Puppeteer it already has one tab open, so if the first thing you did was `const page = await browser.newPage();` you probably have two tabs and need to `.close()` the first one.

Here's a more complete code sample:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    // When the browser launches, it should have one about:blank tab open.
    const page = (await browser.pages())[0];

    // A safer way to do the above is to open a new tab and then close all
    // tabs that aren't the tab you just opened.
    // const page = await browser.newPage();
    // // Close any tabs that aren't the one we created on the line above
    // for (const p of (await browser.pages())) {
    //     if (p !== page) {
    //         await p.close()
    //     }
    // }

    await page.goto('https://example.com/');

    // Ctrl-click the "More information..." link to open it in a new tab
    await page.keyboard.down('Control');
    await page.click('a');
    await page.keyboard.up('Control');

    // Wait a second for the tab to open
    await page.waitForTimeout(1000);

    // Print the URLs of all currently open tabs
    console.error((await browser.pages()).map(p => p.url()));

    if ((await browser.pages()).length !== 2) {
        throw "unexpected number of tabs";
    }
    const otherPage = (await browser.pages())[1];
    // Do something with the other tab
    // ...
    // Then close it
    await otherPage.close();

    await browser.close();
})();
```

On **macOS** this won't work. The shortcut is Command+click so you would have to do `await page.keyboard.down('Meta')` instead of `'Control'`, but that doesn't work because on macOS keyboard shortcuts that use the Command key are usually handled by the operating system, not the browser (things like ⌘-A, which normally selects all text, don't work either). You can try

- middle clicking, as [suggested by @nightowl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59613625)
- Shift-clicking, which opens the link in a new window. Use [`browser.browserContexts()`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.browser.browsercontexts) to find the new window
- running your code under Linux using a virtual machine or Docker container

Answer (score 3):

add `target="_blank"` to the elements you would like to click:

```js
await page.$$eval('.result-lockup__name a', el => el.map(x => x.setAttribute("target", "_blank")));
```

Comment: I have changed the code l(see edit) so instead of clicking of the element, it is clicking on the href attribute. the target _blank attribute is there, but it still opening on the same tab. Can you point why?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a page first on the browser instance and then goto that page.

const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('https://url.com');

Comment: Thank you but I already have this. The point is to be more human, just as a human would do middle click on the mouse on link.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'

(async () => {
    try {
        // Goal function to wait new page and get instance
        async function getNewBrowserTab(browser) {
            let resultPromise

            async function onTargetcreatedHandler(target) {
                if (target.type() === 'page') {
                    const newPage = await target.page()
                    const newPagePromise = new Promise(y =>
                        newPage.once('domcontentloaded', () => y(newPage))
                    )

                    const isPageLoaded = await newPage.evaluate(
                        () => document.readyState
                    )

                    browser.off('targetcreated', onTargetcreatedHandler) // unsubscribing

                    return isPageLoaded.match('complete|interactive')
                        ? resultPromise(newPage)
                        : resultPromise(newPagePromise)
                }
            }

            return new Promise(resolve => {
                resultPromise = resolve
                browser.on('targetcreated', onTargetcreatedHandler)
            })
        }

        // Using
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
        const page = await browser.newPage()

        await page.goto('https://www.google.com/')

        // Click on link with middle button to open in new browser tab
        await page.click('a[href]', { button : 'middle' })

        // Wait for new tab and return a page instance
        const newPage = await getNewBrowserTab(browser)

        // Switch to new tab
        await newPage.bringToFront()

        // Wait a bit to see the page
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))

        await newPage.close()
        await page.close()
        await browser.close()
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
})()
```

[Answer based on puppeteer github](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3718)